# Pragmatically Open Database connection

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio, database-connection

I am working on a project and have scoured the internet for answers on this topic but could not find a single answer, not even an open source solution.

Maybe you guys could help me out.

In visual studio you can open the database connection window by browsing **View -> server explorer -> add connection.** that is all well and known but what if I wanted to open that same form from code or a certain API. I cant seem to figure it out but there must be some sort of way to access this form pragmatically since its native to Visual Studio.

For all who are unsure what form I'm talking about, here's a snippet:

[image]

So my question to you is, how can I , through code, open this window? If there is nothing built into Visual Studio and C#, do you know of any open source software that accomplishes this or will I have to recreate it with a windows form application?

Comment: Why do you want to prompt that form for a user from your code?  If they're accessing the database, they'll be a developer or database administrator, both whom could use Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio.  What benefit would your application provide by trying to access it directly?  You could build the form from scratch, then do SqlConnection.Open() once you've passed a valid path to the database instance.

Comment: I am making a model designed for developers that use SQL server. Its part of a bigger project. So that any developer can use this application to manipulate the same data but from different servers. also, it is important that my form directly mimics the connection page.

Comment: But, why?  Model designed for developers, what is your application trying to **do**.  Why use your application over Visual Studio or Sql Server Management Studio?  **What is the business process you're solving.**

Comment: not to be annoying, but I literally cannot disclose any information that you asked for. Answer accepted below.

Comment: I understand, but without some of that knowledge it’s hard to accurately provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to build the form yourself if you need any custom logic etc in which case you could use the `ConnectionStringBuilder` classes and pass the validated fields from your custom form to the relevant builder class to generate the connection string. Visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders) for more information.

Microsoft also has library on nuget that you could use, although it's deprecated so use with caution. The nuget file, which you can download manually, also contains the source code so perhaps you could use this to jump start your own UI component. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog

Comment: yeah, I have researched that as well and that will be my fallback. I just thought there would be an easier way to prompt that form. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: @ShadowBlade I updated my answer with some more details ^ .

Comment: now that is more what im looking for! our company uses NuGet, so this will be of great help. Im surprised I was unable to find that myself, You saved me alot of research :)